# jQuery str.replace not working

Tags: javascript

I need to search for a string (video embed url) once the page loads and replace the `&` with `&amp;`.  This is the best guess for code that I have tried but it seems to just have no effect:

```
(function ($, document, undefined) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var str = $( "iframe" ).attr( "src" );
        str = str.replace(/&/g,"&amp;");
        $( "iframe" ).attr( "src",str );
    });
})(jQuery, document);
```

There is only once `iframe` on the page and it looks like this:

```
<iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/72874423?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0;api=1' width='615' height='355' style='width:615px;height:355px;'></iframe>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [**It works fine - your problem must be elsewhere**](http://jsfiddle.net/CXgGc/)

Comment: yes, i can see that working fine!

Comment: _“and replace the & with &amp;”_ – what for? Masking `&` as `&amp;` is only necessary for the context HTML, but since your iframe is already in the HTML with just single `&`, this whole thing seems pretty useless to me. (If any browser/client would have a problem with these unmasked `&`, then the damage would already have been done _before_ your JS even gets to work.) I got the slight feeling that the actual problem you want to solve is something completely different.

Comment: The [`replace` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is a native String method and has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that once the javascript manipulates the dom, the `&amp;` is encoded as HTML back to just an `&`. The actual javascript to replace `&` with `&amp;` works fine.

See [this fork](http://jsfiddle.net/wX2qU/) of the commenter's JSFiddle. when the Alert happens, the string has `&amp;`, but once it's written to the document, it displays just `&`

Comment: Ah, I see.  So is there a different way of doing this?  The whole purpose is to get rid of an html validation error for a demo, it doesn't have to be fancy.

Comment: @fender967: You solve validations errors [only] by altering the source file, not by javascript.